# How to show-up AJAX post data from WSForm Wordpress plugin form on the same page?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, forms, plugins

I have [WSForm Pro](https://wsform.com/) form management plugin installed on my Wordpress site. The plugin utilizes AJAX as the only method to post a form's data so that only the form's area is updated on submit, not the whole page. On submit I need to show-up the form's data on the same page.

**What I have done.** Through adding a function to functions.php of my theme I'm able to get the form's data as a session variable:

```
// Add action to process WS Form form data
add_action('wsf_action_tag', 'wsf_action_function', 10, 2);
// My function for action
function wsf_action_function($form, $submit) {
    // Get submit value (Change '123' to your field ID)
    $submit_value = wsf_submit_get_value($submit, 'field_18');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['form'] = $submit_value;
    // Do something with $submit_value here
    // ...
}
```

I also added the following php-code to the page with the form to show-up the session variable above:

```
<?php
session_start();
$form = $_SESSION['form'];
var_dump($form);
?>
```

**The problem.** When I submit the form, nothing changes except built-in success message (as supposed with AJAX), though on page reload the submitted data is shown-up successfully. If I could have my own AJAX script, I would want to modify it slightly to reload the whole page. But since I use a third-party plugin, it's makes the task too complicated.

**The question is** how would I change any part of my code to show-up the form's data on submit on the same page?

Comment: You can't print output to the screen in an AJAX action. `var_dump($form);` should not do anything. Also .. session like this will not work with WordPress.

Comment: @HowardE, many thanks for commenting! I have already realized that no php-code will work on submitting the form. What makes the work done are adding function to functions.php, the php-code above and built-in redirect action (see my post below). The session does work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround in WSForm functionality! From "Edit Form" choose "Actions", "Add", "Redirect" and point the page's redirect to itself.
[Click to to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rne8g.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).